# order by date DESC not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MYSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `timestamp` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UQ_4242c0a8c07abd9adef59c123f76f3827bb47589` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

my query is:

```
 select * from `mytable` order by `date` DESC
```

This is not ordering it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't expect it to be ordered by 'date', since date is varchar.

Comment: perhaps date is a reserved keyword - try changing the column date to date_test and see if it sorts correctly

Comment: Store dates in native formats (such as the aptly named `date` data type) and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that being `date` a varchar it's sorted in lexicographical order, try to cast it to date:

```
 select * from `mytable` order by STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC
```

Anyway this is a temporary solution, you should fix your schema and store it with the appropriate format.

Comment: Agreed. Make date field a date field or datetime as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should create yourdate field as a date data value

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UQ_4242c0a8c07abd9adef59c123f76f3827bb47589` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```